# show this error about hibernate when I run the program

Tags: hibernate-4.x

```
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:213 - Query cache: disabled
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:321 - Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:228 - Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:237 - Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
18:02:32,359 DEBUG SQLExceptionConverterFactory:52 - Using dialect defined converter
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:257 - Echoing all SQL to stdout
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:261 - Statistics: disabled
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:265 - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
18:02:32,359  INFO SettingsFactory:279 - Default entity-mode: pojo
18:02:32,453  INFO SessionFactoryImpl:152 - building session factory
18:02:32,453 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:161 - Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
18:02:32,453 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:164 - instantiating session factory with properties: {hibernate.connection.password=root, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin, java.vm.version=11.0-b15, hibernate.connection.username=root, java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/, path.separator=;, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, user.country=CN, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 3, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, user.dir=E:\workspace\Hibernate, java.runtime.version=1.6.0_10-rc2-b32, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment, java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\endorsed, os.arch=x86, java.io.tmpdir=C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\, line.separator=
, java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., user.variant=, os.name=Windows XP, sun.jnu.encoding=GBK, java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_10/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\bin;D:\CongouV2\Release\ant\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\MySQL\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;D:\WPS Office\9.1.0.4715\office6;D:\UltraEdit\;D:\Eclipse;, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=50.0, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler, os.version=5.1, user.home=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator, user.timezone=Asia/Shanghai, java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob, file.encoding=GBK, java.specification.version=1.6, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, user.name=Administrator, java.class.path=E:\workspace\Hibernate\bin;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\test-classes;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\classes;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\activation-1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ant-1.7.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\asm-2.2.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\asm-3.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\asm-commons-2.2.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-api-1.2.8.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-dom-1.2.8.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axiom-impl-1.2.8.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-adb-1.5.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-codegen-1.5.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-kernel-1.5.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.5.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\axis2-transport-local-1.5.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\backport-util-concurrent.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\barcode4j-2.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-anim.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-awt-util.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-bridge.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-css.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-dom.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-ext.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-gvt.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-parser.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-script.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-svg-dom.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-svggen.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-util.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\batik-xml.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\bcel-5.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\bonecp-0.7.1.RELEASE.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\bsh-2.0b4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\classes12.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\com.efuture.base.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\com.efuture.core.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\com.efuture.esql.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\com.efuture.v3core.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ComboInput.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-dbcp-1.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-digester-1.7.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-javaflow-20060411.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\commons-pool-1.5.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\db2java.zip;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\db2jcc.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\dsws-common.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ExtServlet.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\google-collections-1.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\groovy-all-1.5.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gson-1.6.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\guava-r07.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\GwtAI-API-0.3.zip;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\GwtAI-Client-0.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\GwtAI-Core-0.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\GwtAI-Gailet.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-api-checker.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-dev.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-servlet.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-soyc-vis.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-user.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\gxt.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\hbnpojogen-persistence-1.3.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\hessian-4.0.7.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\hibernate3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\httpclient-4.2.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\httpcore-4.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxjdbc.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxjdbcx.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxlang.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxlsupp.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxsqlj.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ifxtools.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\iText-2.1.7.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\iTextAsian.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\iTextAsianCmaps.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jackson-all-1.9.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-3.7.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-applet-3.7.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-fonts-3.7.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\java40.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\javacup.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jcommon-1.0.15.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jdbcLdap.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jdom.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jfreechart-1.0.12.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jldap-4.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\JNative.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jpa.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jrebel.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jta-1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jtds-1.2.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\jxl-2.6.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\kryo-1.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.9.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\mail-1.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\minlog-1.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\mongo-2.5.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\mongo-2.6.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\msSecurity.zip;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\neethi-2.0.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\ojdbc14.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\olap4j.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\olap4j-jdk14.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\png-encoder-1.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\poi-3.7-20101029.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-3.7-20101029.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7-20101029.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\poi-scratchpad-3.7-20101029.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\quartz-all-1.8.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\retroweaver-1.2.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\retroweaver-rt-1.2.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\rhino-1.7R1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\servlet.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\saaj-api-1.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-apis.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\serializer.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-beans-2.5.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\spring-core-2.5.5.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\sqljdbc4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\struts2-core-2.1.6.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\sybase.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-framework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-sdk-java-20110609.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-sdk-java-all-released-20110609.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-sdk-java-all-released-20110609-source.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-sdk-java-auto_1398074178519-20140421.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\taobao-sdk-java-daily_all-20140319.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmemcached-1.2.4.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmemcached-1.3.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xml-apis-ext.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xrparser.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xr-server.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xr-third.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xstream-1.3.1.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\xwork-2.1.2.jar;D:\CongouV2\Release\gwt\war\WEB-INF\lib\yanf4j-1.1.1.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\ehcache.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\cglib-nodep-2.2.jar;E:\workspace\Hibernate\lib\hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar, hibernate.show_sql=true, java.vm.specification.version=1.0, java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre, sun.arch.data.model=32, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql:///hibernate, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, user.language=zh, java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit, hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer=true, java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing, java.version=1.6.0_10-rc2, java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext, sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\classes, java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc., file.separator=\, java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.desktop=windows, sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86}
18:02:32,468  WARN ConfigurationFactory:127 - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/E:/workspace/Hibernate/lib/ehcache.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2220 - Static SQL for entity: com.xujinfei.events.Event
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2222 -  Version select: select EVENT_ID from Event where EVENT_ID =?
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2223 -  Snapshot select: select event_.EVENT_ID, event_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_, event_.title as title0_ from Event event_ where event_.EVENT_ID=?
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2225 -  Insert 0: insert into Event (EVENT_DATE, title, EVENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2226 -  Update 0: update Event set EVENT_DATE=?, title=? where EVENT_ID=?
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2227 -  Delete 0: delete from Event where EVENT_ID=?
18:02:32,812 DEBUG BasicEntityPersister:2230 -  Identity insert: insert into Event (EVENT_DATE, title) values (?, ?)
18:02:32,828 DEBUG EntityLoader:95 - Static select for entity com.xujinfei.events.Event: select event0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_, event0_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_, event0_.title as title0_0_ from Event event0_ where event0_.EVENT_ID=?
18:02:32,828 DEBUG EntityLoader:95 - Static select for entity com.xujinfei.events.Event: select event0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_, event0_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_, event0_.title as title0_0_ from Event event0_ where event0_.EVENT_ID=?
18:02:32,828 DEBUG EntityLoader:95 - Static select for entity com.xujinfei.events.Event: select event0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_, event0_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_, event0_.title as title0_0_ from Event event0_ where event0_.EVENT_ID=? for update
18:02:32,828 DEBUG EntityLoader:95 - Static select for entity com.xujinfei.events.Event: select event0_.EVENT_ID as EVENT1_0_, event0_.EVENT_DATE as EVENT2_0_0_, event0_.title as title0_0_ from Event event0_ where event0_.EVENT_ID=? for update
18:02:32,828 DEBUG SessionFactoryObjectFactory:39 - initializing class SessionFactoryObjectFactory
18:02:32,843 DEBUG SessionFactoryObjectFactory:76 - registered: 402881ed4807779c014807779dfc0000 (unnamed)
18:02:32,843  INFO SessionFactoryObjectFactory:82 - Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
18:02:32,843 DEBUG SessionFactoryImpl:262 - instantiated session factory
18:02:32,843  INFO SessionFactoryImpl:379 - Checking 0 named queries
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
    at com.xujinfei.test.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:17)
```

Comment: You need to provide more info about your program! What is your code and when you get the error...

Comment: Think you,It has been resolved.My project have hibernate3's jar package and hibernate4's jar package At the same time，caused by the program can't found the method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

caused by Import Jar package was wrong . It's hibernate3 and Others are hibernate4, which replaced all hibernate3.It Has been resolved.